# Java/ test & operation after timeout

Tags: java, testing

I hava a test, with:

```
@test(timeout = 50000)
```

I want to do some operations if the test fails because the timeout, and only then.

I try the next:

```
@Test(timeout=60000)
    public void test1() {
    try{
              // code
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //operations after time out
    }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do what you described here with JUnit's `timeout` parameter because it doesn't provide a callback to handle the operations after it has timed out.

But, you can certainly write your own test harness to do just that. In the below example, I want the code to execute within one second but my actual code execution takes 2 seconds. In this case, we catch the `TimeoutException` and you can perform your additional operation within that catch block.

```
@Test
public void testMe() {

    // test must finish within one second
    int expectedExecutionInSeconds = 1;

    RunnableFuture<String> runnableFuture = new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            // your actual code goes in here
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return "ok";
        }
    });

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.execute(runnableFuture);

    try {
        String result = runnableFuture.get(expectedExecutionInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertEquals("ok", result);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        // stop code
        runnableFuture.cancel(true);

        System.out.println("do other stuff");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        fail("other stuff is failing");
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
}
```